# Use selected items in adding data multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a multiple select form-control where the user choses a lot of options, using these options I need to fill a table in the data base the problem is I need to do so for each selected item, i used a loop but some how it only works for the last selected item , I don't know what part I'm doing wrong :

```
app.ajoutProjet= function () {
      for(var i=0;i<result.data.projetsListe.length;i++){ 
         if(result.data.projetsListe[i].NomProjet==app.ajoutData.NomProjet){ 
          app.ajoutData.projet_id=result.data.projetsListe[i].IdProjet;     
         }
      }
          var compteur=app.test.length;
          var j=0;
          do { app.ajoutData.col_id=app.test[j];
               CP.createCP(app.ajoutData).then(function(result){
               if(result.data.success==true){ 
               console.log("the association result : " +result.data.CP);
               }
               });         
               j++
              }while(j<compteur)            
};
```

The view :

```
<label>Nom du projet:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="NomProjet" placeholder="Entrez le nom du projet" ng-model="ajouter.ajoutData.NomProjet">
<br>
<label>Les collaborateurs:</label><br>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="col_id" ng-model="ajouter.test">
<option ng-repeat="c in collaborateursListe" value="{{c.IdCollaborateur}}">{{c.NomCollaborateur}}</option>
 </select>
```

And the post request :

```
router.post('/ColProjet',function(req , res){
 col_projet.Projet_col.sync({force: false}).then(function () {
 return  col_projet.Projet_col.create({
     IdProjetCol : req.body.IdProjetCol,
     col_id : req.body.col_id,
     projet_id: req.body.projet_i});
```

The service :

```
createCP : function (ajoutData) {
  return $http.post('/api/ColProjet',ajoutData);
  }
```

I am stuck here a while now and can't figure out where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where **app.ajoutData.NomProjet** comes from, but it looks like you're iterating over every item in **projetListe**, and assigning **app.aboutData.projet_id** to the id of the current item.

```
      for(var i=0;i<result.data.projetsListe.length;i++){
         app.ajoutData.projet_id = result.data.projetsListe[i].IdProjet;
```

**CP()** is in an if block checking if **app.ajoutData.NomProjet** is the same as the one in the current item.

```
         if (result.data.projetsListe[i].NomProjet==app.ajoutData.NomProjet) {
```

Since **NomProjet** is never reassigned, only the **projet_id**, CP will only run once if there is only one item that contains that name.

Comment: I removed it from the if block but still the same problem